# Save Value in Lambda to retrieve data in a Next API call

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I'm new to AWS and I have a project where I need to retrieve to data from a Client API and Store into a S3 bucket for processing.

But each time (every5mins) when I run the Lambda function my client send me data of last seven days including the new records. SO, each time when I run this it will create duplicate records in the S3 Bucket.

What I wanted to know is can I read my JSON file during the run time and save the latest date of the JSON object into a variable and pass it (Key/Value) into the GET Methode via API Path when I'm running my Lambda next (in next 5 min) time.

```
var AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });
var s3 = new AWS.S3();
const https = require('https');


var responseBody = {"Message": "If you see this then the API call did not work"};



const doGetRequest = () => {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => { 
      //authentication - added by RG - START
        const username = "xxx";
        const password = "xxx";
        const auth = "Basic " + new Buffer(username + ":" + password).toString("base64");
      //authentication - added by RG ---- END
        
    const options = {
      host: 'www.xxxxxxxxxxx.com',
      path: '/rest/v1/chargeCode',
      headers: { Authorization: auth},
      method: 'GET'
    };
    var body='';
    //create the request object with the callback with the result
    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
      res.on('data', function (chunk) {
      body += chunk;
      });
      res.on('end', function () {
      console.log("Result", body.toString());
      resolve(body);
      });   
    });
    // handle the possible errors
    req.on('error', (e) => {
      reject(e.message);
    });
    //finish the request
    req.end();
  });
};

exports.handler =   (event, context, callback) => {
  
  let date_ob = new Date();
  let year = date_ob.getFullYear();
  let month = ("0" + (date_ob.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
  let day = date_ob.getDate();
  let hours = date_ob.getHours();
  let minutes = date_ob.getMinutes();
  let seconds = date_ob.getSeconds();
  
    const bucket_name = 'Charge Code - ' + year + '-' + month + '-' + day;
    const objectName = 'Charge Code - ' + year + '-' + month +  '-' + day +'-' + hours + '-' + minutes + '-' + seconds +'.json';

      
  doGetRequest().then(result => {
    var response = {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "headers": {"my_header": "my_value"},
        "body": JSON.stringify(result),
        "isBase64Encoded": false     
    };

    callback(null, response);
      
      var data = {
            Bucket: 'commtrac',
            Key: 'V1/Charge Code/'+bucket_name+'/'+objectName ,
            Body: result,
            ContentEncoding: 'base64',
            ContentType: 'application/json',
            ACL: 'public-read'
      };


      s3.upload(data, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            console.log('Error uploading data: ', data);}
        else {
            console.log('succesfully uploaded!!!',bucket_name+' || '+objectName);
            }
    });

   }).catch(error=> {
        callback(error);
  });   
    
    
};
```

I couldn't try anything coz, I have no clue at all.

But what my expectation is save a value into a lambda/or into the lambda folder where it can read during the next time run and pass that value along with the API Path.

This is my API response. in this case I need to read and save the latest'"CreatedWhen":' object.

```
{
"ChargeCodes": [
    {
        "Id": "afd0e27e-6255-11e7-9c08-e09467c3e6fe",
        "Name": "DescriptionLine CC",
        "Description": "Charge Code Used For Description Lines Only, not user viewable etc",
        "ChargeCodeDefinition": "Manual",
        "Contract": "",
        "TaxCode": "",
        "BandingType": "Standard",
        "GLClass": "",
        "GLLocation": "",
        "GLDepartment": "",
        "SalesItem": "",
        "Unit1Definition": "",
        "Unit1Description": "",
        "Unit1DisplayUnit": "",
        "Unit1DecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "Unit1UnitOfMeasure": "",
        "Unit1MinimumValue": 0.0,
        "Unit1ApplyProRata": false,
        "Unit1ProRata": 0.0,
        "Unit2Definition": "",
        "Unit2Description": "",
        "Unit2DisplayUnit": "",
        "Unit2DecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "Unit2UnitOfMeasure": "",
        "Unit2MinimumValue": 0.0,
        "Unit2ApplyProRata": false,
        "Unit2ProRata": 0.0,
        "RateDecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "RateApplyDiscount": false,
        "RateDiscount": 0.000000000,
        "MinimumTotal": 0.000000000,
        "Rates": [
            {
                "Id": "afd0e28a-6255-11e7-9c08-e09467c3e6fe",
                "Order": 2147483646,
                "Field": "Rate",
                "Operator": null,
                "MatchValues": null,
                "MatchUnitOfMeasure": null,
                "Rate": null
            }
        ],
        "CreatedWhen": "2017-07-06T15:16:22.9448726",
        "UpdatedWhen": null
    },
    {
        "Id": "18552aed-d11e-48f9-b2e5-b99cd6a49721",
        "Name": "Surcharge Charge Code",
        "Description": "Surcharge Charge Code used for Surcharge Generation",
        "ChargeCodeDefinition": "Manual",
        "Contract": "",
        "TaxCode": "",
        "BandingType": "Standard",
        "GLClass": "",
        "GLLocation": "",
        "GLDepartment": "",
        "SalesItem": "",
        "Unit1Definition": "",
        "Unit1Description": "",
        "Unit1DisplayUnit": "",
        "Unit1DecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "Unit1UnitOfMeasure": "",
        "Unit1MinimumValue": 0.0,
        "Unit1ApplyProRata": false,
        "Unit1ProRata": 0.0,
        "Unit2Definition": "",
        "Unit2Description": "",
        "Unit2DisplayUnit": "",
        "Unit2DecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "Unit2UnitOfMeasure": "",
        "Unit2MinimumValue": 0.0,
        "Unit2ApplyProRata": false,
        "Unit2ProRata": 0.0,
        "RateDecimalPlacesRoundTo": 0,
        "RateApplyDiscount": false,
        "RateDiscount": 0.000000000,
        "MinimumTotal": 0.000000000,
        "Rates": [],
        "CreatedWhen": "2021-03-09T16:10:49.6860507",
        "UpdatedWhen": null
    }
]
```

}

Comment: This is not technically a question for SO, here is my advice. You have an input you have an output. You really have to merge them. If I were you, the very first thing to try is to read from the the same S3, remove duplicates, add new data and then put it back to S3. Well this is the most simple solution. But doesn't this why DBs exist in the first place? Is there a limitation?

Comment: As I said there are a lot of variables here to consider, hence its though to give a solution.

Comment: @NewUser - thankx for the comment. this is exactly what I have to do. please refer this image. [https://files.fm/u/78emnyrj2#/view/y775thpzh]

Comment: You already have a solution, what help are you seeking?

Comment: the problem I've is every time when the Lambda runs it will read & write a new data set. in the glue it checks duplicates only in the selected data set not with the processed data sets. (I can create another glue job to check processed data duplicate with new data set..

Comment: but still this will be a loop again) since I'm getting last seven days data during each lambda run, I cannot rally on what data glue or brew does. so that I need a solution to get only the latest data from API call. in this case I need to save the latest record ID from the last record and pass that ID to the API call to get only the latest data in the next data fetching. -- Hope you understand the question, my friend???

Comment: 1st Lambda run results >> D1 >> Check duplicates in Glue >> Save in S3
2nd Lambda run results >> D2 >> Check duplicates in Glue >> Save in S3

Basically, I need to check duplicates in both D1 and D2
or
I need to avoid duplicates from Lambda function by reading only the latest data records.